# Visual Studio 2017 does not sign an assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly, strongname

I need to make an assembly, which I have developed in C# under *Visual Studio 2017*, a strong-named assembly.
My customer provided me with an *.snk* file, and I turned on the **Sign the assembly** checkbox in the *Signing* tab of my project properties. Under the hood, in the *.csproj* file the following elements were added:

```xml
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>ZZZ.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
```

**The issue is that the produced assembly is *not* signed.**

Another visible awkwardness, which may indicate the cause of the issue, is that in spite of having

```xml
    <DelaySign>false</DelaySign>
```

in the *.csproj* file, every time I open the *Signing* tab the **Delay sign only** checkbox is in an undefined state as shown below[image]

I am quite lost here and in the community here I trust.
Thank you all in advance for your help.
A few details on the my environment:

```
    Visual Studio Enterprise 2017
    Version 15.9.14
```

The project is in the new format and targets .NET 4.7.1

```xml
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite embarrassing; however, I owe it to the community:
Quoting the question "**The issue is that the produced assembly is not signed.**"
Now, how did I check that the assembly is signed or not? By running *sn -v **bin\x64\Release**\XYZ.dll*
Well, the *bin\x64\Release* indeed contained an obsolete copy of XYZ.dll for the reason, which I could not even remember right now.
The produced assembly is actually placed in *bin\Release\net471*, and running *sn -v **bin\Release\net471**\XYZ.dll* confirms that the assembly is signed...

Well, that is it :o|